# Dell Precision 5530 fans constantly running of docked to USB-C Dock

Tags: 18.04, dell, dock, usb-c

I am running a Dell Precision 5530 with i9 and the NVidea Quattro 2000. Usually I just use the NVidea GPU when doing heavy work and most of the time it is deactivated, so my computer runs very quite. However, as soon as I connect it to the USB-C dock the fans run on full speed almost all the time, event though I do I just do some text processing in LaTex and browse the internet. 
Doing the same things without the dock connected the computer stays quite all the time.

Anybody else has this issue and might have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes am using a Precision 5530, i7, not with the Quattro, but same behavior concerning the USB-C dock. I'm guessing the throughput of the USB-C spec dell is using isn't that great. I've used a macbook pro 2018 15 inch on the same USB-C dock and no problem, but Apple's thunderbolt 3 spec has a really high throughput ability. I think the precision is unable to manage the power coming in through such a small input, and thus the fans take over for managing the power. I'm guessing dell didn't design with this use case in mind, but spec'd the USB-C port for a one use device such as monitor, ethernet, etc, versus 2+ devices on a dock into one port. Best case scenario it could be fixed with a firmware update, more realistically we will be plagued with fan problems until future iterations :/ but that is just my impression, not solely fact based.

Comment: Ok that sounds actually reasonable. Since I need to connect an additional charger when doing demanding tasks on the systems, that the battery does not die. It is actually a very poor design.
Let's hope for a firmware update that might be able to fix it. But as you say no high hopes.

Comment: Just a quick follow up, I found two thermal controlling tools available TLP and thermald from here: https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/ . They can both be installed, and when left on power saver mode, I'm seeing much less fan noise even when USB-C docked. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the chipset or PCH has poor heat dissipation design. It is too hot but the heat still there making the fan keep running. Chipset is active even when the USBC connection under load. It's continuously managing connections and data traffic between various components. This activity generates heat. Just add a thermal pad (probably 3mm) or a combo thermal pad+copper shim+thermal pad to tranfer heat from the chipset to the aluminium bottom cover, the problem will go away. I am absolutely sure.